# Nhibernate sessionPerThread

Tags: c#, nhibernate, concurrency, castle-windsor

I am creating entities in with multiple thread at the same time.
When i do this in sequence order (with one thread) everything is fine, but when i introduce concurrency there are pretty much always new exception.

i call this method asynchronously:

```
public void SaveNewData(){

    ....DO SOME HARD WORK....
    var data = new Data
    {            
        LastKnownName = workResult.LastKnownName
        MappedProperty = new MappedProperty
        {
           PropertyName = "SomePropertyName"
        }
    };

    m_repository.Save(data); 
    }
```

I already got this exception:

> a different object with the same identifier value was already
>   associated with the session: 3, of
>   entity:TestConcurrency.MappedProperty

and also this one:

> Flushing during cascade is dangerous

and of course my favourite one:

> Session is closed!Object name: 'ISession'.

What i think is going on is: Everythread got same session (nhibernateSession) and then it... go wrong cos everything try to send queries with same session.

For nhibernate configuration i use NhibernateIntegration with windsor castle.

**m_repository.Save(data)** looks like:

```
  public virtual void Save(object instance)
    {
        using (ISession session = m_sessionManager.OpenSession())
        {
            Save(instance, session);
        }
    }
```

where m_sessionManager is injected in constructor from Castle and it is ISessionManager. Is there any way how to force this ISessionManager to give me SessionPerThread or any other concurrent session handling ?

Comment: since you are creating a session for every save method call, 'using same session in different threads' is probably is not the problem. It looks like problem is you are trying to save same object in different threads. Session per thread is possible, for that you have to use CurrentSessionContext http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/#architecture-current-session. Further async methods are not guaranteed to run on a different thread.

Comment: Do you have a web project or an application? Because NhibernateIntegration chooses its SessionStorage according to the type of application. For a web application it chooses a SessionStorage that binds to HttpContext and thus may not be thread safe. So you may you FOR TESTING m_sessionManager.OpenSession(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) to force a new session without caching and observe, if something changes.

Comment: It is an application. Also i already solved this issue by upgrade to new Nhibernate.Facility which supersede NhibernateIntegration. This new facility supports Session per transaction. I ll try to summarize it to answer for future generations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i researched and it seems that NHibernateIntengrationFacility doesnt support this transaction management out of the box.

I solved it when i changed to new Castle.NHibernate.Facility which supersede Castle.NHibernateIntegration - please note that this is only beta version currently.

Castle.Nhibernate.Facility supports session-per-transaction management, so it solved my problem completely.